# How to register IMobileServiceClient using Caliburn.Micro.PhoneBootstrapper

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ioc-container, caliburn.micro, azure-mobile-services

After reading through [an excellent intro](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-with-caliburn-micro-in-windows-phone-8-the-theory/) to Caliburn.Micro, there is one thing I seem to have missed out on, and that is [how to register a class with a constructor which is expecting arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.aspx)?

The line in question here is:

`_container.PerRequest<IMobileServiceClient, MobileServiceClient>();`

```
public class Bootstrapper : PhoneBootstrapper
{
    private PhoneContainer _container;

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container = new PhoneContainer();

        _container.RegisterPhoneServices(RootFrame);
        _container.PerRequest<MainPageViewModel>();
        _container.PerRequest<IRepository, Repository>();
        _container.PerRequest<IMobileServiceClient, MobileServiceClient>();
        AddCustomConventions();
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand on @flo's answer a bit here.

When the concrete type you are trying to build accepts types via its constructor that you have already registered with the container, then Caliburn.Micro will automatically provide that type with what it needs when it tries to create it.

For example, If you have a concrete class named `MyClass` that accepts an object of type `IHell` and another one of type `IHeaven` like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(IHell hell, IHeaven) { }
}
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
container.PerRequest<IHell, ConcreteHell>();
container.PerRequest(IHeaven, ConcreteHeaven>();
```

Now when Caliburn.Micro tries to create instances of `MyClass` it will pull `IHell` and `IHeaven` from the container.

Now back to your problem, it seems that [`MobileServiceClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.aspx) only accepts primitive types via its constructor like `string`, `Uri` and other types that you can't register directly with the container.

In this case you have two options:

1. Create a factory that creates `MobileServiceClient`s, something like `IMobileServiceClientFacotry` and `MobileServiceClientFactoryImpl` then register those with the container and inject them into types that need to create instances of `MobileServiceClient` and use them there.

   This is the more suitable solution from a software engineering point-of-view but it requires the overhead of two more types.
2. Register the type using the [**Handler**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container&referringTitle=Documentation) mechanism, which is used to simulate factories:

   ```
   container.Handler<IMobileServiceClient>( iocContainer => new MobileServiceClient("http://serviceUrl.com:34"); );
   ```

   This solution is faster and more suitable when you don't need the over-complexity of factories in huge applications.

Answer (score 0):

The PhoneContainer works as a IoC Container. This means, that Constructor Dependencies would be solved for you on Creation of the concrete Instance:

```
public class MobileServiceClient : IMobileServiceClient
{
 private IRepository _repository;

 // repository is resolved and injected by PhoneContainer 
 public MobileServiceClient (IRepository repository)
 {
  _repository = repository;
 }
}
```

However if you need to remain in control of the injection. In case of a different LifetimeMode, you can configure the instance in the Bootstrapper:

```
this.container.RegisterPerRequest(
                typeof(IMultiSelectionContext),
                null,
                new MobileServiceClient(new RepoXy()), null)));
```